# ASP.Net Life Cycle And Control State And View State

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle

In msdn , they mentioned as, view state values is loaded between page_init and page_initcomplete. Lets us assume , during the get request I am assigning a value to text property of text box as get with in `page_load () { if(!IsPostBack) {textobx.text="get";}}`  . So this get value is stored in viewstate and visible in browser. And during my next postback I am assigning a post value to same text property in `page_init`  event . So as per msdn , after `page_initcomplete` event this post value must be override by the get value . But it doesn't happen that way . Why ?

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "hello";
        }
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text.ToString();

    }
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
            base.OnPreInit(e);
            TextBox1.Text = "init";
    }
    protected override void OnInitComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
            base.OnInitComplete(e);
            TextBox1.Text = "init";

    }
```

First time the value is hello in `Textbox2.Text` this is fine . But during post back I am expecting init value on `textbox2.text` . But it is still hello. why ?

Comment: after page_initcomplete event this post value must be override by the get value ? what is the value you are expecting.you are initializing in !IsPostBack so you will get "get" in textobx.text unless you have changed it somewhere

Comment: @Kristof is right: What ARE you trying to do?

Comment: @Alexander I am just trying to understand the page life cycle.I am clear in this part rite now .Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not quite correct in your ViewState assumption. As described in [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), the ViewState is loaded AFTER `InitComplete`.

Meaning, whatever you write into the control's properties in `Init` or `InitComplete` (which btw is not recommended at that point of the Life Cycle) will definetly be overwritte by the ViewState between `InitComplete` and `Load`.

The behaviour your page is showing is correct.

Comment: So load viewsate happens after InitComplet event . so what does the viewstate  tracking that happen between Init and initComplete event?

Comment: The article says, "View state tracking enables controls to persist any values that are programmatically added to the ViewState collection."

In other words, "ViewState tracking" means nothing else that "ViewState is up and running and available for use".

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for more information on the lifecycle.
The "problem" is that with every POSTback you Post data to the server. The server will take this post data and bind it to the view Controls.
This bind action takes place in the Load event which happens after the Init event.
So what your code currently does during a postback is :
Call init, create controls and your custom code sets the Text value to Init.
Call load, bind all post data to the controls(Including the "hello").
 Since it is not a postback the text property will not be reset to "Hello"(but it's there due to the post data).

Comment: Since I am adding ` protected override void OnInitComplete(EventArgs e)
        {
                base.OnInitComplete(e);
                TextBox1.Text = "init";

        }`

Comment: `InitComplete` is called before the ViewState is restored, so your text will be overwritten.

Comment: In InitComplete event i am assigning `TextBox1.Text = "init";` . So this should not override during postback rite ?

Comment: @Alexander As per msdn ViewState tracking happen between Init and initcomplte what does it mean ?

Comment: @Dhinesh Viewstate tracking is turned on when your OnInitComplete hits. But after you made a tracked change to your textbox it gets overwritten by the post data in your load event. Maybe try to explain what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Whatever you do in `InitComplete` WILL be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

From  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.90%29.aspx :

`PreInit:-`If the request is a postback, the values of the controls have not yet been restored from view state. If you set a control property at this stage, its value might be overwritten in the next event.

Viewstate is loaded in OnPreLoad